# UITableView in UIScrollView with activated paging enabled in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a question to use UITableView in xib file attaching to UIScrollView with checked paging enabled.
I am not native speaker in english, so please see this carefully.

[image: The result of this for first page]
[image: The result of this for second page]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var menuScrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var pageScrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let V1: View1 = View1(nibName: "View1", bundle: nil)
        let V2: View2 = View2(nibName: "View2", bundle: nil)

        self.addChildViewController(V1)
        self.pageScrollView.addSubview(V1.view)
        V1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        self.addChildViewController(V2)
        self.pageScrollView.addSubview(V2.view)
        V2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        var V2Frame: CGRect = V2.view.frame
        V2Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
        V2.view.frame = V2Frame

        print("view width:",self.view.frame.width, "v2 origin x:",V2.view.frame.origin.x)
        self.pageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 2, self.pageScrollView.frame.height)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

The first page shows the little bit of second page but I coded ,as shown as above code,

```
V2Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
```

I thought this would work to fit width of the view but it doesn't.
I want the View1 and View2 to fit the UIScrollView.
I really appreciate to give me a help.

Comment: print the v1.view.frame and v2.view.frame , and compare it's width with the screen width. i think the matter maybe the frame width is not correct

Comment: When I make the nib as a UIViewController in the same way, It works fine, but when I use UITableViewController as a nib and try to attach to ViewController, this happens.